# Trigger Condition

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, triggers

I'm facing problem for write trigger and set conditions.
let see an example as below:

User A has balance 100$ but after user perform transaction 50% of 100% I want to insert into one table but for insert the recorded I only need once a time when the balance less then 30% I want to insert again into a table but I don't know how to set the condition?

Below is the trigger that I write :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRG_BALANCE_TRACK
  AFTER UPDATE ON TABLE_A
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :OLD.ACC = '00000123' AND
     :OLD.BALANCE <> :NEW.BALANCE THEN
    INSERT INTO TABLE_B
      (ACC, BALANCE, DATE_TIME)
    VALUES
      (:NEW.ACC, :NEW.BALANCE, SYSDATE);
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: `if :new.balance in (30,50)` is the condition based on your example. For using percentage calculation instead of hardcoding, then multiply the respective ratio to the `:old.balance` like `0.3*:old.balance`.

Comment: How about the balance 40% it <50 but it >30 so when I have to insert 50% already I don't want to insert again for 40% until it falls to >=30%. because when user perform transaction balance always movement sometimes it falls to 49%, not 50%

Comment: Post some sample data with create table and insert statements. Then show you desired output.

Comment: Example:
I have table_c that have field account, track_bal, and percentage and table_a has field balance so when customer perform the transaction the table_a always update the balance

Comment: when the balance updated I want to insert into table_b  follow check condition field TRACK_BAL of table_c if the balance <=50% and >30% I want to insert into table_b but for next transaction if the balance still falls to the condition above I don't want to insert the same value unless the balance <=30% then I insert again. and when the balance >50% I want to clear the recorded from table_b to history something like that. Thanks and Regards,